# Enormous ime padding in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ime, samsung

I have a pinned bottom container with a textfield. And i use imePadding modifier. When keyboard appears seems like imePadding works twice. It happens only on some devices. Particular my is Samsung Galaxy A80 (Android 11)

Code example

```
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            bottomBar = {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .imePadding()
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red),
                ) {
                    BasicTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        value = "some text",
                        onValueChange = {},
                    )
                }
            },
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding()),
            ) {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    repeat((0..100).count()) {
                        item {
                            Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp).background(Color.Blue)) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]
[image]

**UPD**
Issue reproduce when I add:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Comment: Adding some code snippets may help to solve this issue

Comment: @Srimani789 here the example
When I don't use imePadding on BasicTextField container devices without issue doesn't adjust the screen and there is no padding as expected. But in the same case problematical devices still have imePadding exectly to textfield

Comment: Hey @VadimZhukov have you managed to resolve your issue? I am observing a similar thing happening on some Samsung devices.

Comment: @scana nope. Just removed FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue; more specifically, some devices would seem to ignore adjustResize, but adding imePadding alongside adjustResize would cause others to double it up.

I solved it for myself in the following way:

1. Set the manifest option to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`
2. Set imePadding wherever needed.
3. If setting imePadding on the contents of a scaffold, I also called, `consumeWindowInsets(contentPadding)` on the Modifier of those contents, before imePadding, otherwise the contentPadding got consumed additively in the imePadding.

Something like:

```
Scaffold(...){ contentPadding -> 
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(contentPadding)
            .consumeWindowInsets(contentPadding)
            .imePadding()
    ){...}
}
```

I can't guarantee that this is best practice or that it works in all cases, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. 'consumeWindowInsets(contentPadding)' solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to activity in AndroidManifest.xml file `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. The activity's layout will be resized to ensure that all of its visible content remains visible even when the soft keyboard is shown without using any `imePadding()` modifiers.

here you can see improved code.

```
var value by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), value = value,
                onValueChange = { value = it }
            )
        }
    },
) { paddingValues ->
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp, 16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
    ) {
        items(100) {
            Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Text(text = "Item $it",  modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```